# Network plot colors do not match legend

Tags: r, plot, legend, igraph

I have an igraph network which I want to color with RColorBrewer. Vertices have a "sector" attribute, which I want to use to color them. To do this, I have defined a color palette based on sectors:

```
color.range <- brewer.pal(nlevels(as.factor(V(g)$sector)), name = "Dark2")
V(g)$color  <- color.range[as.factor(V(g)$sector)]
```

When I plot my graph, colors of the legend do not match the information in the "sector" attribute of my vertices:

```
plot.igraph(g,
        vertex.label = ifelse(V(g)$indegree > 5, V(g)$sector, NA),
        vertex.label.family = "Arial",
        vertex.label.color = "black",
        vertex.label.cex = 0.5,
        vertex.frame.color = NA,
        vertex.color = V(g)$color,
        vertex.size = 3,
        layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,
        edge.arrow.mode = 1,
        edge.arrow.size = 0.2)

legend("topleft",
        legend = levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector)),
        col = levels(as.factor(V(g)$color)),
        pch = 19,
        cex = 0.8,
        title = "",
        bg="transparent",
        bty = "n")
```

On the plot I see the categories of some high degree vertices and comparing them with the legend, colors do not match:
[example plot where colors on graph do not match legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEYES.png)

My question is: how can I define a color range that will actually match my sector  categories OR how can I create a legend that represents colors properly. Unfortunately I don't know which one is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are computing the colors for the legend incorrectly. If instead, I use

```
col = color.range[as.numeric(levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector)))]
```

the colors in the legend match the labeled points in the graph.

Comment: for me as.numeric(levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector))) returns NAs instead of some integers representing the levels of the factor.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution of G5W as not completely working as

```
levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector))
```

returned the levels as a list of strings that could not be turned into numbers, so I have got an error:

```
Warning message:
In legend("topleft",legend = levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector)),col = 
color.range[as.numeric(levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector)))],: NAs introduced by coercion
```

I have added one more as.factor() instead and it seems to work now:

```
col = color.range[as.numeric(as.factor(levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector))))],
```